# SpriteSheet buffered image array

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, sprite-sheet

```
public BufferedImage[] sprites1()
{
    BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            sprites[(i * 2) + j] = bigImg.getSubimage(j * 64, i * 64, 64, 64);
        }
    }
    return sprites;
}

public BufferedImage[] sprites1Fliped()
{
    BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(64, 64, sprites1()[i].getType());  
            Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();  
            g.drawImage(sprites1()[i], 0, 0, 64, 64, 64, 0, 0, 64, null);  
            g.dispose();
            sprites[i] = dimg;
        }
    }
    return sprites;
}


ImageIcon img1a = new ImageIcon(images.sprites1()[5]);
ImageIcon img2a = new ImageIcon(images.sprites1()[2]);
ImageIcon img3a = new ImageIcon(images.sprites1()[3]);
ImageIcon img4a = new ImageIcon(images.sprites1()[0]);
ImageIcon img5a = new ImageIcon(images.sprites1()[1]);
ImageIcon img6a = new ImageIcon(images.sprites1()[4]);


    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    layout.add(l1); //l1 is a label with img1a, l2 img2a, ect.
    layout.add(l2);
    layout.add(l3);
    layout.add(l4);
    layout.add(l5);
    layout.add(l6);
    add(layout);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    add(b1, c);
```

[image: Frame]

The problem is the the panel is supposed to show the orange, yellow, then blue dragon from the sprite sheet. Instead it shows a flipped orange dragon, a orange dragon, and a flipped blue dragon.

[image: SpriteSheet]
(This is 128x192)(Each is 64x64)

Comment: How is your plane built? Definitely not by above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by putting the image in the correct folder, replacing the old sprite image sheet.